# How can you block access form internet explorer in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have made the decision to cut ties with internet explorer until they add support for some common W3 approved items. Namely 'multiple' in forms as well as about 5 other things...

As such, I would like to urge my visitors to use a better browser.

Is there a way to setup an http handler or perhaps something in the asax file to route all ie users to a custom page?

## **EDIT**

I know I can use this to get the browser, I'm just not sure how to make a handler to handler the header of the request and then redirect if it is IE

HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser

Comment: Regarding your edit:  `if (internetExplorer) return RedirectToAction(yourAction)` or `return RedirectToUrl(yourUrl)` in your controller method.

Comment: What are `multiple in forms`?

Comment: @Omar it is an attribute that allows you to in a single box add multiple files to a form using shift or ctrl click, been around for 5 years and ie is the only one of the big browsers that does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okie dokie,

The site is setup so that you have to login to use the site so on the logon page I have done this.

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
        return RedirectToAction("IE", "Home");
    else
        return View();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use this:

http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/

[image]

If you just want to detect Internet Explorer so that you can notify the user that multiple file upload capability is not available in their browser, look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Robert i would like it to be for all versions of ie

Comment: @Chase: Oh, I'm sorry.  I didn't realize you wanted to **[block 46% of all users on the internet.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)**

Comment: @Chase Aucoin - This is a very good answer and the last few versions of IE are good - the reason I and most other pros do not use them is because we have extensions or features we like in others... but... IE works very well for many users.

Comment: @Wil I do get the choice of what browsers I want to support and IE isn't one of them. but having to use flash as a work around for multiple file upload is just as bad as asking them to download a different browser so I choose firefox, chrome or webkit over flash. it's a personal decision.

Comment: @Chase - a quick look at the gem @Robert linked to shows it would be quite trivial to modify to do what you need, or at least provide you with a starting point for your own implementation.

Comment: @Chase: Ah, that is aggravating, isn't it?  Why didn't you just say that in the first place?  Well, it's easy enough to **[detect Internet Explorer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx)**  Just detect it, and display a message stating that if they want multiple file upload capability, they'll have to use a different browser.

Comment: @Tim there as is something to be said for the logic being handled server side as then i do not have to expend the bandwidth to serve up content that I don't care for them to have access to with IE.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery on client site, another option is using the [jReject plugin](http://jreject.turnwheel.com/):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $.reject({
             reject: {
                 safari: true, // Apple Safari  
                 chrome: true, // Google Chrome  
                 msie: true, // Microsoft Internet Explorer  
                 opera: true, // Opera  
                 konqueror: true, // Konqueror (Linux)  
                 unknown: true // Everything else  
             }
         }); // Customized Browsers  

         return false;
     });
```